# "open in terminal" command in ubuntu 16.04, doesn't open terminal in changed directory

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, gnome-terminal

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS `open in terminal` command in right click menu always start the terminal with `/home/user` as working directory. Is there anyway to make it's functionality same as `nautilus-open-terminal` where terminal opens with current working directory where I have right clicked? I am using `zsh` as my default shell.

Comment: which file manager are you using?

Comment: Use your file manager and navigate to the desired location. Right-click on the white space in the files window and choose *Open Terminal here*.

Comment: @rancho I use nautilus.

Comment: @ipselute I know what you are saying but I want my terminal's working directory to the place where I right clicked not `/home/user` .

Comment: @vikrant: Open a Terminal window and type: cd /path_to_desired_directory.  cd is the command for changing the directory. Replace /path_to_desired_directory with your desired location (like /folder/subfolder/subfolder/...). *Open Terminal here* works for me in Thunar.

Comment: You must've clicked the wrong directory when you did the right-click and Open Terminal. I checked on your machine in front of you that it works correctly.

Comment: Are you trying to open a directory that you don't have permissions for? Please [edit] your question to include the output of `ls -alFd <directoryname>` where directoryname is the directory you are trying to open in the terminal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I guess I've found a fix for this. So, launch terminal go to `Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Command` and uncheck the option saying `Run a custom command instead of my shell`.

Comment: My config is already uncheck it but I check and uncheck and all is working good, thanks

Comment: But it's not working with Desktop :(

Comment: Yes, that's annoying actually. But, if you're browsing the Desktop as a folder inside nautilus, it works fine.

Comment: But I want to use zsh with this checked.

Answer (score 0):

Type in a Terminal window: `sudo su`, hit `Enter` and then type `nautilus`. In the Nautilus window right-click and choose `Open Terminal here`.

What `sudo su` did was to switch from current user to root user (superuser/admin). It means that your current user doesn't have enough privileges to do that action (`Open Terminal here`). You need to go to User Accounts and elevate the current user account rights (in Advanced Options, some checkbox for User monitors system changes or something like that). That's how it looks in my Xubuntu, in Unity might be some different names, but it surely is something about user rights.

Answer (score -1):

Try using krusader file manager. It has built in terminal emulator that opens in same directory.

Type in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install krusader
```

Comment: no i don't want to install any new file manager. I think what i am asking is also possible in nautilus file manager.